# Going to dates in the past in calendar program

Tags: mysql, sql-server, vb.net

I have a program I am working on where all the events on given dates in a SQL DB populate a calendar. I recently switched from MYSQL to MSSQL 2012 and I am now getting the error `"Conversion failed when converting date and/ or time from character string."`

here is the code that forms the date

```
   '// Set Start and End Date
    If numericMonth < 10 Then
        doubleMonth = "0" & numericMonth 'If Month was September  doubleMonth = 09 
        startDate = numericYear & "-" & doubleMonth & "-01" ' If date was June 1 2015 startdate would = 2015-06-01
        Calendar1.Refresh()
    Else
        startDate = numericYear & "-" & numericMonth & "-01"
        doubleMonth = numericMonth
    End If
    Dim endDate As String
    If numericMonth < 10 Then
        endDate = numericYear & "-0" & numericMonth & "-31"
    Else
        endDate = numericYear & "-" & numericMonth & "-31" ' If date was June 30 2015 enddate would = 2015-06-31
    End If



    If bypassMode = "0" Then




        count = 0
        dbQuery = "SELECT * FROM SOEVENTS WHERE DATE BETWEEN '" & startDate & "' AND '" & endDate & "' ORDER BY date ASC"

        If SQL.HasConnection = True Then
            SQL.RunQuery(dbQuery)
        End If
```

The final Outcome is formatted yyyy-mm-dd. All future months work but it seems every 3rd month in the past does not.

Comment: Parse a string to `datetime` _before_ you passs it to the database. Therefore use `Date.Parse` or `Date.TryParse`. Then [use sql-parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlparameter(v=vs.110).aspx) to provide this parameter. On that way you avoid localization and conversion issues and more important, sql-injection. So never ever use string concatenation to build your sql query.

Comment: Use Dates to query the database. You are making like very error-prone and complicated for yourself converting everything to a string. `Dim startDate As New DateTime(year, month, day)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The efficiency and security of your code notwithstanding, the obvious problem is that 5 of the 12 months do not have a 31st day and in these cases you are trying to assign dates that are invalid. VB knows how to count calendar units (e.g. months) properly when you use its methods, but assigning an invalid date from a string produces an error. Try this instead:

```
Dim endDate As DateTime = startDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1)
```

Comment: I do have code to check the days in the selected month. Thats what i don't understand this method worked with MySQL, but Now im Using MSSQL and im getting errors.

Comment: The code you posted formats `endDate` to always end with "-31" and concatenates it into `dbquery` without performing any other functions on it. Where is the code that checks the last day in the month? How is it being called here? Since handling invalid date formats is something that is quite possibly different between SQL compilers (2015-02-31 may very well be valid in MySQL but invalid in MSSQL), why don't you test this to make sure? If you're opposed to using a `DateTime` variable, as in my answer, you could just try changing "-31" to "-28". The result will tell you if this is your problem.